# Realm: How to get the current size of the database

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

Is there a Realm API method to get the **current database size** of my RealmSwift app using RealmSwift as data storage? So that I could display that information in the app itself (like statistic information).

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Realm's APIs doesn't offer such a method. But for these purposes, it seems to be sufficient to use [Foundation's `NSFileManager` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error:).

```
let realm = …
let path = realm.configuration.fileURL!.path
let attributes = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(path!)
let fileSize = attributes.fileSize()
```

Note though: the reported file size is not completely occupied by data. For performance reasons, Realm is acquiring more disk space beforehand. If you want the disk usage of the actual stored data, you would need to write a compacted copy first and could measure that, but this seems to be for the use-case of reporting it to an end-user rather misleading and would hit the performance.

#### Update:

Realm is using `NSURL` for paths since version 0.99+. The sample code was changed accordingly.

Comment: Hi marius. Many thanks for that quick one. Works perfect for me. Just on sidenote: `attributes.filesize` did not exist (maybe only with Swift 2.0) but I figured out, getting this value by using filesize as key.
`let fileSize = attributes[NSFileSize] as! NSNumber`
So thanks again. Cheers. John

Comment: Hey John, glad that it worked. It was a typo. `fileSize()` should work as it is exposed as a method in a category on `NSDictionary`.

Comment: what is this result? mine was f.e. `32768.0` is this Byte?? so fairly 32KB?

Comment: Yes, this is the size in Byte. If you want to learn more why exactly 32KB, [you can learn more about the file size growth in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27402831/4194189).

Answer (score 8):

Updated version for Swift 3

```
func checkRealmFileSize() {
    if let realmPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.relativePath {
        do {
            let attributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath:realmPath)
            if let fileSize = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as? Double {

                print(fileSize)
            }
        }
        catch (let error) {
            print("FileManager Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this result? mine was f.e. `32768.0` is this Byte?? so fairly 32KB?

Comment: @DavidSeek it's byte