# sending a database/Realm using Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, realm, multipeer-connectivity

I have an admin and a user app. Basically, I will build the database(realm) using Admin app then send the whole database to the user app.

Here is the path to my database:

```
let directory: NSURL =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.example.file")!

let fileURL = directory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm")
```

//What should I do to the path so I can send it via `MultiPeerConnectivity : MCSession`

```
try session.sendData("my Realm File To Send", toPeers: session.connectedPeers, withMode: .Reliable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to write a compacted copy of your Realm file via [`writeCopyToURL(fileURL: _, encryptionKey: _)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm14writeCopyToURLFzTCSo5NSURL13encryptionKeyGSqCSo6NSData__T_). Read [more about Realm's file size growth behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402831/4194189) to understand why that is a good idea.

You can then simply read the file contents via `NSData(contentsOfURL: _)`.

```
let parentURL = fileURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!
let compactedFileURL = parentURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("compact.realm")
try! realm.writeCopyToURL(compactedFileURL)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: compactedFileURL)!
```